# Crashing in observeValueForKeyPath which attached to NSOperationQueue operationsCount

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, key-value-observing, nsoperationqueue

I have `UITextView logView` (tried both `atomic` and `nonatomic`) and `NSOperationQueue uploadQueue` properties in my UIView subclass.
I've added KVO on my `NSOperationQueue` property's `operationsCount` like this:

```
[[self uploadQueue] addObserver:self
            forKeyPath:@"operationCount" 
               options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                        NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
               context:NULL];
```

Observer function looks like this:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass: [NSOperationQueue class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Keypath is: %@ change dictionary is: %@", keyPath, change);
        NSInteger testnew = [[change objectForKey: @"new"] integerValue];
        NSInteger testold = [[change objectForKey: @"old"] integerValue];
        if (testnew > testold) {
            [[self logView] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Uploading %d files", testnew]];
            objc_setAssociatedObject([self logView], @"max_value_of_uploads", [change objectForKey: @"new"], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
        } else {
            NSInteger value = [objc_getAssociatedObject([self logView], @"max_value_of_uploads") integerValue]; 
            [[self logView] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Uploaded %d of %d files", testnew, value]];
        }
    }
}
```

`uploadQueue` filling works like that:

```
   ...
   NSDictionary *iter;
        NSEnumerator *enumerator = [objects objectEnumerator];
        while (iter = [enumerator nextObject]) {
            Uploader *op = [[Uploader alloc] initWithFileName: [iter objectForKey: @"fileName"] 
                                                             FileID: [[iter objectForKey: @"fileID"] integerValue] 
                                                       AndSessionID: [self sess]];
            //Uploader *op = [[Uploader alloc] init];
            [[self uploadQueue] addOperation: op];
   ...
```

Without `if-else` block, everything works just fine: I've got NSLog messages about number of operations in queue, numbers are ok and so on.
But with that `if-else` block, I get crash, which looks like this:

```
bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x10617fb0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   WebThreadLock
2   -[UITextView setText:]
3   -[SincViewController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]
4   NSKeyValueNotifyObserver
5   NSKeyValueDidChange
6   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:]
7   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:usingBlock:]
8   ____NSOQDelayedFinishOperations_block_invoke_0
9   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:]
10  -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:usingBlock:]
11  __NSOQDelayedFinishOperations
12  _dispatch_after_timer_callback
13  _dispatch_source_invoke
14  _dispatch_queue_invoke
15  _dispatch_worker_thread2
16  _pthread_wqthread
17  start_wqthread
```

It crashes in `else` block. 
Moreover, I don't see any changes to my logView.
Thanks for future help and responses.

**UPDATE:** `performSelectorOnMainThread` when setting text saved me.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244243/nsoperation-observer-and-thread-error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When updating your UI, make sure that you're in the main thread. A possible solution follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if (testnew > testold) {
        [[self logView] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Uploading %d files", testnew]];
        objc_setAssociatedObject([self logView], @"max_value_of_uploads", [change objectForKey: @"new"], OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY);
    } else {
        NSInteger value = [objc_getAssociatedObject([self logView], @"max_value_of_uploads") integerValue]; 
        [[self logView] setText: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Uploaded %d of %d files", testnew, value]];
    }
});
```

Note that using `dispatch_async` or `dispatch_sync` depends on your desired implementation, but in the latter case, you risk deadlocking unless you check what thread you're in.

See also: [NSOperation, observer and thread error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244243/nsoperation-observer-and-thread-error)
where someone suggests moving your UI code to a separate method:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(dataLoadingFinished:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

.. which is a fine alternate route.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the delegate pattern here. You seem to be mixing very advanced techniques with some loose code, which can lead to problems very quickly. I don't think you need the associative object for example.

Your error occurs because you are accessing UI from a background thread by the way. You should wrap you UI calls (setText:) inside performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: or a block.

Comment: That's what written in error, yep.
But I don't really use observer function in any thread other from main thread. 
I think that problem lays in the KVO internal mechanism, maybe it uses additional threads? 
Anyway, `performSelectorOnMainThread` when setting text saved me.

Comment: the observer will be called in whatever thread the change occurred in. And you are using an NSOperationQueue, so yes it will be in the background.

Comment: But i can't get it. Change occurring after NSOperation instance gone from queue. That's happens with NSOperationQueue, which "lives" in the main thread. I mean, causing event obviously happened in so called background thread, but the change it self must happen in main thread. Where am I wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Read the answer linked about. Apple even tells you not to do it.

Comment: I've read. But in addition to just believe I would like to understand them.

Comment: In the world of iOS if the Apple documents say don't do this it is usually as close to understanding as you can get. It is possible to speculate, reverse engineer, disassemble or just plain make things up but you probably won't ever understand exactly why. I do give you credit for trying to understand, well done, many people don't bother. For this particular problem what you are trying to do does have a bad code smell. I can't explain it better than saying generally threads and the observer pattern are very bad combinations. You could ask them. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell